Is there a tool that statically analyses a terraform project and generates the AWS IAM policy required by a role to run said project?
Crafting access policies for roles that run tf projects is painful.
I'm searching for a tool that statically analyses a tf project and generates the AWS IAM policy required by a role to run said project.
Alternatives I've found for generating role policies:

Requiring a permissive role initially

IAM Access Analyzer (reviewing cloudtrail)
IAMLive (intercepting AWS CLI calls)


Requiring some manual sorting

Policy Sentry (grab every arn and sort them into action categories)



I don't like the retroactive nature of requiring a permissive role as it's temporarily less secure and kludgy to use; especially when one has to repeat this process for each iteration of one's IaC.
I dislike the manual sorting method for obvious reasons, although it seems better than nothing.
I'm also considering that it may be my poor architectural decisions leading to this desire in the first place:

I have a generic pipeline role that can create other roles.
Each project has a locked-down role creation repo/pipeline that creates a role for each other repo in the project.
Each of those roles runs its respective repo's tf code via pipeline.

